# Apache2: Access files within another directory than /var/www

Tags: javascript, apache

Consider the following setup:

Apache2 is getting the index.html page from

```
/var/www/
```

Within the index.html page I want to include some javascript files which are located here:

```
/media/MyFolder
```

e.g.

```
/media/MyFolder/data.js
```

I tried to use absolute path within index.html:

```
<script src="/media/MyFolder/data.js"></script>
```

This is not working as apache tells me

```
[error] File does not exist: /var/www/media
```

**So my question:**
How can I define sth. like includes (as e.g. in C++) for the apache where I can specify further directories that should be searched for my javascript files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add alias in your apache vhost file:

```
Alias /media /media
```

Or link /media directory in /var/www

```
ln -s /media /var/www/media
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Your /var/www is the default path for the web content. You can create some alias to go in an other place if you want to. You also can create a virtual server (/etc/apache2/sites-available) in an other place.